# Node.js RESTful API validation error on array schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, rest, api-design

I am creating a RESTful API using Node.js and mongoose by following the tutorial by [Acedemind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY&index=10&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q). I have got it working just fine and am now expanding it to allow the client to post several products in the same order. Basically I am modifying a simple "POST" request to be an array instead of some variables. My problem is that I run into a long validation error that hinders the array from being created. Here is the code for the post request:

```
    router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {

      const productsMaybeFalses = await Promise.all(req.body.products.map(async ({ productId })=> {
        const product = await Product.findById(productId);
    if (!product) {
      return false;
    }

    return {
      ...product,
      productId,
    }
  }));

  const errors = productsMaybeFalses
    .map((productMaybeFalse, index) => {
      return {
        productMaybeFalse, index
      }
    })
    .filter(({ productMaybeFalse }) => !productMaybeFalse)

  if (errors.length) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }

  console.log(productsMaybeFalses);

  const products = productsMaybeFalses
    .filter((productMaybeFalse) => productMaybeFalse);


  const order = new Order({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    products: products
  });

  return order.save().then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    res.status(201).json(results.map((result) => ({
      message: "order stored",
      createdOrder: {
        _id: result._id
        },
        request: {
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/" + result._id
        }
    })));
  })

  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    })
  })
})
```

And here is the Schema for the Order:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  productId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product", required: true},
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 1}
});

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  products: [pSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema)
```

To keep this question from being too long I will only post the end part of the error. The part that I feel tells the most information abut the problem. If anyone wants the whole error message to better understand the problem and maybe come up with a solution for me I will be very willing to post it as well. Here it is:

```
kind: 'Array',
        value: [Array],
        path: 'products',
        reason: TypeError: value[i].toObject is not a function
    at DocumentArray.cast (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:309:27)
    at DocumentArray.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:755:12)
    at model.$set (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:922:18)
    at model._handleIndex (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:740:14)
    at model.$set (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:697:22)
    at model.Document (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:114:12)
    at model.Model (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:73:12)
    at new model (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4324:13)
    at router.post (/Users/axelhagman/Documents/Jacobs/api/routes/orders.js:70:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) } },
  _message: 'Order validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
POST /orders/ 500 440.085 ms - 7622
```

I am very new to using node.js and creating API overall so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you do console.log(value) and post that thing here as well. Also do you have your code pushed to github. So that I can take a look at whole flow?

Comment: Here is the github repo for my code. The branch I am working on is APIShoppingCart, keeping the original working version from the tutorial in the master branch. I am unsure of where you want me to console.log(value) (sorry). https://github.com/axelhagman/Jacobs/tree/APIShoppingCart @zenwraight